# Find the exact area of the surface obtained by rotating the curve about the x-axis.

Tags: calculus

$$4x=y^2+20,\quad 5 \leq x \leq 13$$

Here's what i have done:

\begin{align*}
A &= \int{2\pi y\, \mathrm d s},\text{ since the curve is rotated about the }x\text{-axis}\\
&=\int{2\pi y\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}}\;\mathrm d y\\
&=\int_0^{4\sqrt{2}}{2\pi y \sqrt{1+(y/2)^2}\;\mathrm dy},\quad\text{since }\;x=\frac{1}{4}\left(y^2+20\right)\\
&=\int_0^{4\sqrt{2}}{\pi y \left(4+y^2\right)^{1/2}\;\mathrm d y}\\
&=\pi \left.\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(4+y^2\right)^{3/2}\right|_{\,y=0}^{\,y=4\sqrt{2}}\\
&=\text{get stuck after this}
\end{align*}

Okay so i was able to get $\frac{\pi}{3}(216-5\sqrt{5})$ as the next step and $72\pi$ as the answer. is this correct?

any help is appreciated!

Comment: What's the problem? If everything you've done is right so far, you just have to substitute in the two endpoint values for $y$ and subtract.

Comment: @ajd yeah im stupid! i got this (π/3) (216 - 5√5) as the next step and got 72pi as my answer. does that seem correct?

Answer (score 2):

Contrarily to the first comment above, you are wrong from the beginning because of writing $dy$ instead of $dx$ in your integral, and because $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is $2/y,$ not $y/2.$
\begin{align*}
A &=\int_5^{13}{2\pi y\sqrt{1+\left(y'\right)^2}}\;\mathrm dx\\
&=2\pi\int_5^{13}{y \sqrt{1+(2/y)^2}\;\mathrm dx}\\
&=2\pi\int_5^{13}\sqrt{y^2+4}\;\mathrm dx\\
&=4\pi\int_5^{13}\sqrt{x-4}\;\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac{8\pi}3\left.(x-4)^{3/2}\right|_{x=5}^{x=13}\\
&=\frac{8\pi}3(27-1)\\
&=\frac{208\pi}3.
\end{align*}